# 550 Operation not permitted when deleting file through FTP - But I have permissions

Tags: permissions, ftp, webserver, filezilla

I am deleting a Drupal installation from a server I just got access to.
Most of the files deleted just fine, but for some of the files, FileZilla gives

> 550 Operation not permitted

Initially I thought maybe root is owner of these files or something like that, but It turns out that I can chmod them to 777 through FileZilla, but still not delete them.

So, I can chmod the files, but not delete them through FileZilla. I don't have shell access, and there is nothing like cPanel. Furthermore I can't find any information about the OS or anything. It's a weird host.

Any ideas as to what may be wrong here?

Here's the log when trying to delete one of the files:

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Connected
Status: Deleting "/sites/default/default.settings.php"
Command:    CWD /sites/default
Response:   250 CWD command successful
Command:    DELE default.settings.php
Response:   550 default.settings.php: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To delete a file, you need to have write permissions to the parent directory, not to the file itself.

Comment: This did it. A subfolder had 077 permissions, once I chmodded that I could delete the others

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a "limit" in my proftpd.conf by extension files.

```
<Limit STOR STOU RNFR RNTO DELE>
      Order deny, allow
      AllowFilter ^[a-zA-Z0-9-_].*\.(xml|XML|txt|TXT)$
</Limit>
```